# create html from r file containing markup code

Tags: r, shiny, markup

I have an R file which contains:

```
---
    runtime:shiny
output:html_document
- --

### Here are two Shiny widgets
'''{r echo = FALSE}
selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20)
```

I have a 'build' file:

```
setwd('C:/Bla/Shiny/Markup')

rmarkdown::render("ShinyMarkUp.R")
```

which is meant to product the html file from the r file: ShinyMarkUp.R (see above) in the older: C:/Bla/Shiny/Markup

I am getting this error:

```
Quitting from lines 3-11 (ShinyMarkUp.spin.Rmd) 
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : 
  <text>:6:3: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
7: selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
8:               choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20)
     ^
```

Is there anything I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The "ShinyMarkUp.R" file is really an Rmarkdown file input, not a proper R script. What if you changed the extension from R to Rmd as is customary?

Comment: sorry about my ignorance. first time I try to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else - create file ShinyMarkUp:

````
# Example RMarkdown document
This is an interactive document written in *markdown*. As you can see it is easy to include:
1. Ordered lists
2. *Italics*
3. **Bold type**
## This is heading two
Perhaps this introduces the visualisation below.

```{r, echo=FALSE}
sliderInput("sampleSize", label = "Size of sample",
  min = 10, max = 100, value = 50, step = 1)
renderPlot({
  hist(runif(input$sampleSize))
})
```
````

and use this:

```
library(markdown)
library(shiny)

setwd('C:/Bla/Shiny/Markup')

rmarkdown::run("ShinyMarkUp.Rmd")
```